# High Concurrency Clusters in Databricks

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

This from Databricks docs:

> **High Concurrency clusters**
>
> A High Concurrency cluster is a managed
> cloud resource. The key benefits of High Concurrency clusters are that
> they provide Apache Spark-native fine-grained sharing for maximum
> resource utilization and minimum query latencies.
>
> High Concurrency clusters work only for SQL, Python, and R. The
> performance and security of High Concurrency clusters is provided by
> running user code in separate processes, which is not possible in
> Scala.

- Why is this not possible for Scala? Prime aspect of this question.
- Apache Spark-native fine-grained sharing for maximum resource utilization and minimum query latencies. I have a good idea how Spark works, but may be a clarification here in case there is some extra consideration.
- As an aside then, are most then all running their own standard clusters per person or using HAC's using SQL etc. I think HAC's would be the way to go - in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

High Concurrency clusters are intended for use by multiple users, sharing the cluster resources, and isolating every notebook, etc.  For all mentioned languages, separate processes are created and they execute the code that is limited to API exposed by Spark to that language.  But Scala code will be executed inside the Spark JVM (per machine) that is shared between all users, so you can get access to everything that is inside JVM.

Typically, when using High Concurrency clusters, the [Table ACLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/access-control/table-acls/table-acl) are also enabled (only for SQL or SQL+Python), so you can control who can access which data, enforce row/column level access control, etc.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly pls? Of course i get the notion of concurrent usage. I get the jvm of course but each user has own jvm? clearly missing something. batch spark apps under yarn run concurrently.

Comment: I've added the clarification that JVM is shared between users

Comment: May be I am real ignorant but I always learnt and observed that we have for a Spark App our own JVMs for Driver and set of Executors (with YARN). That appears to not be the case on Databricks?

Comment: When running on a cluster, each Spark application gets an independent set of executor JVMs that only run tasks and store data for that application.  from the docs

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that incorrectly - it's a JVM per machine - driver + executors... But anyway, the main point that if you're running the JVM-based code, then you have access to everything

Comment: JVM-based code (Scala, ...) is not isolated inside the JVM, while code in other languages is isolated per user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227759/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-alex-ott).

Comment: @thebluephantom did you ever get clarity on this topic? If so can you pls share.

Comment: @Gadam. a DB cluster has one driver so it appears. it is not a cluster with say Yarn. with scala one cannot effectively multi task like in a noisy cluster. i suspected that from a project in the past.

Comment: @thebluephantom  Do you have a reference for "DB cluster has one driver".  And this is only true of scala applications?  Seems like it would be a poor design, and cause scalability problems.  Why would databricks solve the "high concurrency" challenges of SQL/Python but not Scala?

Comment: @DavidBeavon. check with answer provider

Comment: @DavidBeavon High Concurrency here means the multiple users, not software concurrency... Spark cluster (not yarn cluster) is always one: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html#components

Comment: @AlexOtt are we saying that with scala all users are running their code on the same spark driver program? Or just the same JVM with different threads?

Does this also imply we don't have any separation between users on a standard cluster?

Comment: @AlexOtt it is fairly clear that there is one driver program in a Scala cluster.  It is called the "driver daemon" and runs on the driver node.  But your answer needs to explain WHY there must be only one driver program, as compared to SQL, Python, and R where there can be many.  My understanding is that this is an oddity that is specific to Databricks. Open source Spark (OSS) allows multiple applications to be running on the cluster in separate/independent driver processes.

Comment: @DavidBeavon Databricks cluster is different from standalone clusters, yarn, mesos, etc. it’s always consists of driver and executors and you can’t submit new driver inside it. Standalone cluster in Spark consists of workers that can accept multiple executors. You can think of DB cluster as of able to accept only one set of executors. If you need multiple jobs, you spin multiple clusters. It’s not the same design as you have on premise when you always have running machines where you share resources

Comment: I’m thinking that you are mixing the master that is able to run multiple jobs consisting of driver and workers with Spark jobs/tasks executing inside a single jobs. Spark process is able to execute multiple subtasks inside it, but driver has a scheduling overhead. That’s true for OSS Spark and DB

Comment: @AlexOtt I'm thinking of multiple applications running in a cluster, each with their own driver logic.  You can still submit multiple scala jobs to an all-purpose databricks cluster.  But they are just all hosted in the same silly "driver daemon" process on the "driver node" of the databricks cluster.   The drivers suffer from some sort of resource synchronization that slows them way down.  Even with lots of cores, we see that our (independent) jobs are being synchronized because of some unknown resource conflict, and the result is that only one core of the "driver node" is used.

Comment: It’s the same problem in OSS Spark. Just run Indepedent jobs. Use instance pools if you worried about startup time. Also, interactive clusters that allow to run multiple jobs are more expensive, just use “normal” jobs

Comment: @AlexOtt  a standard cluster would not be comparatively expensive if I could host a dozen concurrent jobs in it (as you can with OSS).  To your point, the "job clusters" can take three minutes to start, even with pools.  It is crazy long.. especially if some of my applications may complete in ten minutes or less.  It is clear that the "high concurrency" clusters are solving a performance bottleneck in Databricks.  The wierd thing is that Databricks never elaborates or describe that problem, nor tell us why they are reluctant to fix the equivalent problem on the Scala side of things.

Comment: I'd love it if Databricks explained why "high concurrency" clusters exist, what problems/bottlenecks are avoided, what compromises are made to attain these benefits, and how they are internally working differently than a standard cluster.  Most importantly they need to explain why Scala was left out in the cold.

Answer (score 4):

A "high concurrency" cluster is an attempt by Databricks to recreate the performance of normal open source spark (OSS).  In normal OSS, multiple applications on a cluster run **independently** of one another.  See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

In OSS, the Spark driver logic is hosted in separate/independent processes.  Spark applications are co-equals that share the cluster hardware. This is the type of environment that is suitable for a data engineer who wants to maximize the utilization of the available hardware for concurrently running applications.

But Databricks aims to develop a **stateful** or **collaboration** experience for "data scientists" who wish to share the cluster and the related notebooks.  To accomplish these goals, Databricks has developed a stateful cluster technology via their "driver daemon".  It is a single process running on the driver node which coordinates any driver logic that needs to run on the cluster.

When you consider the standard Databricks cluster (ie. an "all-purpose" cluster), you should think of it as a cluster that has the **opposite** qualities of the "high concurrency" cluster.  (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure)

- High concurrency clusters have "fine-grained sharing".  Whereas the default clusters do a lot of intentional resource synchronization (causing temporary conflicts) within the context of the "driver daemon".  This is most evident when lots of simultaneous jobs are being submitted.
- High concurrency clusters have "maximum resource utilization".  Whereas the default cluster will often be bottlenecked on internal resources within that JVM process ("driver daemon"), and the cluster will rarely use more than **one** CPU core on the driver node (implying the serialization of all driver logic executing in the cluster).
- High concurrency clusters have "minimum query latencies", whereas latencies on a default cluster become very high - even when there are only 5 or 10 independent jobs running.
- High concurrency clusters "run user code in separate processes", whereas a Databricks cluster will host all driver logic in a single massive JVM process (aka the "driver daemon").  That process becomes a substantial bottleneck for a variety of technical reasons.

In conclusion, the Databricks architecture is built around a single "driver daemon" process (JVM code that was developed primarily with Scala).  This can become a bottleneck for certain Spark workloads.  But the language bindings for SQL, Python, and R are already designed in a way that executes them outside of the JVM (into a separate "runtime"/"sidecar").  So I'm guessing it was easier to make the adjustments to the architecture that would minimize the concurrency conflicts for those languages when they are already executing in their own sidecars.

In contrast to those languages (SQL, Python and R), the Scala-based logic is assimilated into the "driver daemon" process itself, and doesn't have a separate runtime. A high concurrency mode for Scala could be accomplished, but probably not without the avoidance of that "driver daemon".  That would be a massive reversal in their architecture. And it would basically take the platform back to looking like OSS again.  They may believe it diminishes their competitive advantages, or it would result in some confusing incompatibilities between their cluster modes.

Comment: You can think of the Databricks cluster as an interactive Spark job that as usual consists of the driver & worker.  They are running on machines allocated from the pool of machine of cloud provider, and usually you're only limited by provider's quotas.  These "jobs" are coordinated by external cluster manager. From that perspective, the architecture is similar to the OSS Spark - you have some "cluster manager" that is responsible for the allocating resources for execution, and you have machines to execute on.

Comment: But in OSS cluster you usually have a fixed set of machines on which you're running the Spark jobs. In Databricks you're usually only limited by number of machines that your cloud provider may allocate for you.  Clusters on Databricks are used for interactive workloads, when people developing the code, building models, etc. - if you need to execute a batch job you should use Databricks jobs that will execute on a separate set of the nodes. And they are cheaper. You can run jobs on the existing clusters, but it's usually not recommended, and they will be more expensive